# How to use `randomize_property` with bundled property graph in boost graph library?

Tags: c++, boost, graph

In the documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/random.html#randomize_property

There is only a function prototype, I cannot find a working example.
I tried several things but it just cannot compile.
Here's a simple source code:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/random/linear_congruential.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/erdos_renyi_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

struct EdgeProperty {
  int cost;
}; 

typedef adjacency_list<
        setS, // disallow parallel edge
        vecS, 
        undirectedS,
        no_property,
        EdgeProperty
> Graph;

typedef erdos_renyi_iterator<minstd_rand, Graph> ERGen;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  minstd_rand gen(time(0));
  assert(argc >= 3);
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  double p = atof(argv[2]);
  Graph g(ERGen(gen, n, p), ERGen(), n);

  // randomize_property< [unknown class] >(g, gen);

  return 0;
}
```

Update: the code provided by @phooji works. I added a default constructor for the `EdgeProperty` and my code compiles too:

```
struct EdgeProperty {
  EdgeProperty(int x = 0) : cost(x) { }
  int cost;
};
```

The original compilation error is posted as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/935682), which I cannot understand. Hope someone tell me how this works.

Comment: Seems to be a recurring question on boost-users: http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2005/09/14033.php and http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2009/08/50755.php -- doesn't look like it was resolved either time.

Comment: @Cubbi Yes I found that too. He gave up doing it using bundled properties.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but I was trying to figure out how to disallow parallel edges, and your code sample gave me the answer. Much obliged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles for me:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/linear_congruential.hpp>

struct myedge {
  myedge(int x) : testme(x) {
  }
  int testme;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, // disallow parallel edge
  boost::vecS,
  boost::undirectedS,
  boost::no_property,
  myedge
  > mygraph;

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  mygraph g;

  // auto pmap = boost::get(&myedge::testme, g);
  boost::minstd_rand gen(0);
  boost::randomize_property<boost::edge_bundle_t>(g, gen);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS; // :)
}
```

Hope that helps -- I don't have time to actually test it, so apologies if this isn't what you're after.

Comment: Thanks. Your code compiles. That is so odd, the only difference between your code and mine is that your bundled edge property class `myedge` has a constructor. I added the constructor and the code compiles. Cannot figure out why. Hoping for an explanation :)

Comment: @Ivan Z. Xiao : Note that this is a single-argument constructor not labeled "explicit", meaning the following compiles: `myedge m = 5;` Or, more importantly, `m = gen();` compiles.

Comment: @Cubbi Arrr... Thanks for pointing out this. If I do not wrongly interpret it, the compiler must make a implicit cast by calling the default constructor for `myedge m = 5;`

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one problem I can see, which is invalid edge property definition. To define graph properties the `property<>` type should be used. There are several predefined properties kinds, like index, weight, color, etc. To define edge cost the `edge_weight_t` property kind is used. Therefore, the graph type definition should be as following:

```
typedef adjacency_list<
      setS, // disallow parallel edge
      vecS,
      undirectedS,
      no_property,
      property<edge_weight_t, int>
> Graph;
```

To access the property type the `property_map<>` is used: `property_map<Graph, edge_weight_t>::type`.

**Edit** My mistake regarding bundled properties, still it's hard to provide correct type for the template parameter of `randomize_property<Property>`, which should be the property *kind*. If you define the graph as in my example, the usage will be `randomize_property<edge_weight_t>(g, gen);`

Comment: his property is not invalid, it's bundled, as in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html

Comment: @Cubbi You are right it was my mistake regarding bundles. However, the bundles as a property maps complicates usage of `randomize_property<>`, since the `Property` templete parameter expects a property kind like `edge_weight_t` or `vertex_index_t`, which are difficult to derive from the bundle.

Comment: Bundled property is more intuitive so I use it. In their document they said they will deprecate interior property in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following workaround until it is properly sorted out by boost:

```
boost::detail::randomize_property<int EdgeProperty::*> 
      (g, gen, &EdgeProperty::cost, boost::edge_bundle_t);
```